# R remove duplicate data from each column

Tags: r, duplicates

I get CSV's with hundreds of different columns and would like to be able to output a new file with the duplicate values removed from each column. Everything that I have seen and tried uses a specific column. I just need each column to be unique values.

For Example My Data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), C = c("Mr.","Mr.","Mrs.","Miss","Mr.","Mrs."))
df
    A B    C
  1 1 1  Mr.
  2 2 0  Mr.
  3 3 1 Mrs.
  4 4 0 Miss
  5 5 0  Mr.
  6 6 1 Mrs.
```

I would like:

```
    A B    C
  1 1 1  Mr.
  2 2 0 Mrs.
  3 3   Miss
  4 4   
  5 5    
  6 6
```

Then I can:

```
write.csv(df, file = file.path(df, "df_No_Dupes.csv"), na="")
```

So I can use it as a reference for my next task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), C = c("Mr.","Mr.","Mrs.","Miss","Mr.","Mrs."))


for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  assign(paste("df_",i,sep=""), unique(df[,i]))
}

require(rowr)
df <- cbind.fill(df_1,df_2,df_3, fill = NA)
```

> ```
>   V1 V1   V1
> 1  1  1  Mr.
> 2  2  0 Mrs.
> 3  3 NA Miss
> 4  4 NA <NA>
> 5  5 NA <NA>
> 6  6 NA <NA>
> ```

or you could do

```
require(rowr)
df <- cbind.fill(df_1,df_2,df_3, fill = "")
df
```

> ```
>   V1 V1   V1
> 1  1  1  Mr.
> 2  2  0 Mrs.
> 3  3    Miss
> 4  4        
> 5  5        
> 6  6
> ```

If you want to avoid typing the name of each intermediate dataframe you can just use `ls(pattern="df_")` and `get` the objects named in that vector or use another loop.

If you want to change the column names back to their original values you can use:

```
colnames(output_df) <- colnames(input_df)
```

Then you can save the results however you, like, i.e.

`saveRDS()`

`save()`

or write it to a file.

Putting it all together:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), C = c("Mr.","Mr.","Mrs.","Miss","Mr.","Mrs."))


for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  assign(paste("df_",i,sep=""), unique(df[,i]))
}

require(rowr)
files     <- ls(pattern="df_")

df_output <- data.frame()
for(i in files){
  df_output <- cbind.fill(df_output, get(i), fill = "")
}

df_output <- df_output[,2:4] # fix extra colname from initialization
colnames(df_output) <- colnames(df)
write.csv(df_output, "df_out.csv",row.names = F)

verify_it_worked <- read.csv("df_out.csv")
verify_it_worked
```

> ```
>   A  B    C
> 1 1  1  Mr.
> 2 2  0 Mrs.
> 3 3    Miss
> 4 4      
> 5 5      
> 6 6
> ```

Comment: This works for the current data set however I sometimes have 100 or more columns so typing out df_1, df_2... would not work. So after the For loop when I have every column outputted into values can I run another loop to to grab every value starting with df_ and combine into 1 file? Also if the headers could be the original name that would be perfect.

Comment: @Trigs Yes, sure. You can also us `ls()` to get a list of the objects in your environment with a certain `pattern`, i.e. `ls(pattern="df_")`. If you want to change the colnames it's just `colnames(output_df) <- colnames(input_df)`

Comment: Looks like it is adding another column of NA so everything is shifted right. Column A is all NA. Also this is a huge help so thank you!

Comment: @Trigs Oh I see what you're saying. A weird result of how I created the object. I will add one line to fix it right now. You're welcome for the help. Please feel free to upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`read.csv` and `write.csv` work best with tabular data. Your desired output is not a good example of this (every row does not have the same number of columns).

You can easily get all the unique value for your columns with

```
vals <- sapply(df, unique)
```

Then you'd be better off saving this object with `save()` and `load()` to preserve the list as an R object.

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet to work with a flexible number of columns, remove duplicate columns, and preserve column names:

```
require(rowr)

df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), C = c("Mr.","Mr.","Mrs.","Miss","Mr.","Mrs."))

#get the number of columns in the dataframe
n <- ncol(df)

#loop through the columns
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){

  #replicate column i without duplicates, fill blanks with NAs
  df <-  cbind.fill(df,unique(df[,1]), fill = NA)
  #rename the new column
  colnames(df)[n+1] <- colnames(df)[1]
  #delete the old column
  df[,1] <- NULL
}
```